# Video Recorder Issue in Blackberry

Tags: video, blackberry, recorder

I've implemented video recording feature in my application and it works fine on all the popular BB devices with OS versions 6.0 and later except BB Torch.

In BB Torch, the recorder is getting displayed only half the device screen. When I tried to set the displaySize or displayFullScreen, it throws media exception that these functions are not supported. But in BB Bold/Curve etc, it's not throwing this exception.

Is there any way that this issue can be fixed ? Please help.... Thanks in advance !!!

Please find the code snippet below.

```java
public void videoPlayer() {
    try
    {
        // Start capturing video from the camera
        m_oPlayer = javax.microedition.media.Manager
                .createPlayer("capture://video?" + strEncoding);

        m_oPlayer.realize();

        m_oPlayer.start();
        m_oVideoControl = (VideoControl) m_oPlayer
                .getControl("VideoControl");

        m_oRecordControl = (RecordControl) m_oPlayer
                .getControl("RecordControl");

        m_oZoomControl = (ZoomControl) m_oPlayer
                .getControl("javax.microedition.amms.control.camera.ZoomControl");

        // Initialize the video display
        Field oVideoField = (Field) m_oVideoControl.initDisplayMode(
                VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE,
                "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");
        /**
         * To make the video recorder layout fit the entire size of the device.
         */
        try {

            m_oVideoControl.setDisplaySize(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());

        } catch (MediaException mex) {
            //System.out.println(mex);
            videoExceptionAction(mex.getMessage());
        }
        VerticalFieldManager oVfmMainManager = (VerticalFieldManager) this.getMainManager();
        oVfmMainManager.add(oVideoField);
        m_strVideoFile = strFilePath;
        m_oOutStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        videoExceptionAction(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the code you use to display the player, and set its size.  thanks.

Comment: @Nate please find code snippet below  
    m_oPlayer = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("capture://video?" + strEncoding);
m_oPlayer.realize();
m_oPlayer.start();
m_oVideoControl = (VideoControl) m_oPlayer.getControl("VideoControl");
m_oRecordControl = (RecordControl) m_oPlayer.getControl("RecordControl");
m_oZoomControl = (ZoomControl) m_oPlayer.getControl("javax.microedition.amms.control.camera.ZoomControl");
// Initialize the video display
Field oVideoField = (Field) m_oVideoControl.initDisplayMode(VideoControl.USE_GUI_PRIMITIVE,
      "net.rim.device.api.ui.Field");

Comment: try {
    
 m_oVideoControl.setDisplaySize(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
 } catch (MediaException mex) {
                                 //System.out.println(mex);
     videoExceptionAction(mex.getMessage());
  }

Comment: With BB Torch, it's going to the catch block..... and it says setDisplaySize not supported

Comment: Thanks, but please use the **edit** link below the question, and paste your code in there.  Then, make sure to format it with the **{ }** button.  We really can't read code that's pasted into the comments.

Comment: @Nate code has been added along with the question itself...please check and let me know

Comment: Have you tried holding the Torch oriented in landscape mode when you run this code?  It might be preserving the video aspect ratio, and when held in portrait mode (vertically), it might need to shrink the video height to roughly half the screen size, to get the width equal to the screen width.  Anyway, try running in both configurations, and make sure the width and height parameters are correct (width > height for landscape).

Comment: @Nate In landscape mode the camera is getting displayed in full screen....but on portrait only half the screen is coming....I also noticed that when we open the native video recorder of the Blackberry Torch device, on portrait mode, there also only half the screen size is getting displayed; but they have centralized the video capture display...

So, Is there any alternative solution for this or we need to close this declaring it a known issue from RIM ??